What is the angle?

The puzzle is by the brilliant Catriona Agg.

Picture:

 

Explanation:
Add a 180° rotated copy of the original figure creating a square with four quarter circles at its corners.
Add the two new red lines by taking perpendiculars to the existing red lines from the bottom left and top right corners.
Observe that each of the just introduced red lines is the axis of symmetry to one of the yellow circles and the perpendicular red lines. It follows that the intersection points are also mirror symmetric. The grey isosceles triangles are my clumsy way of highlighting this fact.
Infer that the blue dashed lines are shifted copies of the diagonal of the centre red square.
Conclude that the desired angle is

 45°


How do we know that the centre red rectangle is a square?

@noedne because the outline of the entire figure is a square and we drop the four red lines from its four corners.

Trick Solution:

 Since the proportions are not specified, we can assume that the angle remains constant even if we alter the sizes of the sectors. Given that, we can shrink the yellow sector along the horizontal axis until its center meets the orange sector. Then it is obvious that the measure of the angle is 45°.


 


Unless it's a trick puzzle that's asking for the angle assuming the figure is drawn perfectly to scale ;-)

This is how I figured out the answer but then used coordinate geometry to convince myself that it is indeed independent of the radii.

Synthetic Solution

 

The measure of the major arc of circle O between points F and B is 360° - 90° = 270°, so the measure of the inscribed angle FAB is 270°/2 = 135°, and the measure of the supplementary angle BAD is 180° - 135° = 45°.

The measure of angle BCD is also 45°, so angles BAE and DCE are congruent, and because opposite angles AEB and CED are also congruent, (green) triangles AEB and CED are similar by AA similarity.

Therefore, the lengths of their corresponding sides are proportional: EA/EC = EB/ED, which can be rearranged into EA/EB = EC/ED. Because opposite angles AEC and BED are congruent, (blue) triangles AEC and BED are similar by SAS similarity.

Finally, angle CAE is congruent to its corresponding angle EBD, which measures 45°.


Answer:

 45°

Explanation:

 I originally had a proof using coordinate geometry, but after seeing @noedne’s answer, I came up with the following proof. It starts out the same way as @noedne’s answer but differs from it later on.


 Consider the image below. As @noedne argued, the angle EAB is 135°, so the angle BAC is 45°. Now consider the blue circle with diameter BD. It passes through C because the angle BCD is 90°. The angle BDC is clearly 45°, so A must also lie on the blue circle. It follows that the angles CAD and CBD are equal, and it’s clear that the angle CBD is 45°. 


To make it count as a solution you must also provide the proof that the intersection point is on the blue circle.

@FlorianF I added a proof

Inversive Solution

 

Let B and D be the points besides O where line PQ intersects circles P and Q, respectively. We want to show that lines AQ and BC and circles BAO and COQ all intersect at a point X. Consider an inversion centered at O, resulting in the following diagram:



We want to show that lines A'B' and C'Q' and circles A'OQ' and B'OC' all intersect at a point X'. If we let X' be the intersection of lines A'B' and C'Q', then quadrilateral A'OQ'X' is an isosceles trapezoid and therefore cyclic, and quadrilateral B'OC'X' has opposite interior right angles at B' and C' and is therefore also cyclic, verifying the claim.

Because quadrilateral CXOQ is cyclic, angle CXQ is congruent to angle COQ, which measures 45°.


Coordinate Solution

Fix a coordinate system with origin at the yellow circle's center, scaled so that the yellow circle's radius is 1 and the orange circle's radius is $r$. The negatively sloped line has equation $y=-\frac1{r+1}x+1$. We claim that the positively sloped line passes through $(-1,0)$ and has equation $y=\frac r{r+2}(x+1)$. Solving for the intersection,
$$\begin{align}&y=-\frac1{r+1}x+1=\frac r{r+2}(x+1)\\\implies&x=\frac{1-\frac r{r+2}}{\frac1{r+1}+\frac r{r+2}}=\frac{(r+1)(r+2)-r(r+1)}{(r+2)+r(r+1)}=\frac{2r+2}{r^2+2r+2}\\\implies&y=\frac r{r+2}\cdot\frac{r^2+4r+4}{r^2+2r+2}=\frac{r(r+2)}{r^2+2r+2}\\\implies&x^2+y^2=\frac{4(r^2+2r+1)+r^2(r^2+4r+4)}{(r^2+2r+2)^2}=\frac{r^4+4r^3+8r^2+8r+4}{r^4+4r^3+8r^2+8r+4}=1,\end{align}$$
so it is on the yellow circle and the claim is true.

Put $\alpha>0$ and $\beta<0$ for the measures of the angles formed with the $x$-axis by the lines with slope $\frac r{r+2}$ and $-\frac1{r+1}$, respectively, and $\theta=\alpha-\beta$ for the desired angle measure. Then
$$\tan\theta=\frac{\tan\alpha-\tan\beta}{1+\tan\alpha\tan\beta}=\frac{\frac r{r+2}+\frac1{r+1}}{1-\frac r{r+2}\cdot\frac1{r+1}}=\frac{r(r+1)+(r+2)}{(r+1)(r+2)-r}=\frac{r^2+2r+2}{r^2+2r+2}=1,$$
so the angle measures $\boxed{45^\circ}$.

